# Python Django set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE when migrating source code

Tags: django, python-2.7, settings

**Task:** Set up a new running environment by being provided python/Django source code and some additional details.

**Problem:** Cannot get Django-admin to validate due to missing/incorrect settings configuration
"**django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured** Requested setting USE_I18N, but settings are not configured. ..... "

> You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings

Env Details: Ubuntu OS, Python 2.7, Django 1.7, PostgreSQL (also Supervisor + gunicorn) Running a venv located **/home/dave/python-env/vas/**bin/activate

Python sys.path

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/* (multiple defined)
/home/dave/python-env/vas/python2.7/site-packages
```

So tried several methods (including #export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project-name.settings....) with little success.

How can one set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE variable?
os.environ.setdefault() is set in wsgi (I know this is the next step)
BUT this value is also set in /manage.py ...?

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", project_name.settings)
```

The directory /var/www/app/ (where the python source code is located) has several files, one of them is the project_name where the settings.py sits....
I am new to python/django...

Trying to get django-admin.py validate to validate.

**Update:** Running #python manage.py runserver runs OK. #python manage.py validate|check returns "System check identified no issues (0 silenced)

Running #django-admin.py check returns the error in question. "You must either define DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE ...."

**UPDATE 2: Solution**
Turns out you don't need django-admin.py as suggested by (Alasdair) and you can use manage.py.

Details - If the 'manage.py check' function returns no issues and #pip install -r requirements.txt completes within your virtual environment THEN one can run #manage.py createsuperuser

I was able to use #manage.py runserver after creating a super user, and using this new user (as the database tables were empty for security reasons) I was able to log into 127.0.0.1:8000/admin. From there the models/tables were visible and using the admin functions I could create a new user + group to access the original system that was being migrated as an admin user.
Also not that a database was required (running postgres) with db/username/pass as per settings files and a git repository (at least empty initialised) for raven...

hope this helps someone coming into python.

Comment: Usually, you should only use `django-admin` when you are creating a new project. After that, use `manage.py` instead, and it will take care of `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` for you. For example `./manage.py runserver`. Note that `./manage.py validate` is deprecated in Django 1.7 and removed in Django 1.9.

Comment: what is your project structure? And what are the exact commands that you tried and failed?

Comment: Thank you for your comments: runserver and validate|check do work for manage.py. If django-admin.py does not work (as per message above) I cannot create a new admin user....

Comment: Any recommendations for 'the right way to migrate python code'? i.e. minimal things that are needed. I feel so close yet so far...